# Formgroup can't retrieve values of user input and page reload on form submit IONIC 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I've tried to search before asking this but it seems like there's no answer for now. My problem is that i try to implement a login page using ionic 5 (I'm a beginner with this framework), i think everything is fine but my formgroup can't retrieve values of user input and page reload when i click on create user but i never write the code for this.

Here's my code (sign-in.page.ts)

```
import { UserService } from './../user.service';
import { User } from './../models/user';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.page.scss'],
})
export class SignInPage implements OnInit {

  public loginForm: FormGroup;
  public user: User;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, public userSevice: UserService, public router: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      login: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      confirmedPassword: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  saveUser() {
    console.log("saveUserCalled");
    console.log(this.loginForm.value);

    this.user.login = this.loginForm.value.login;
    this.user.eMail = this.loginForm.value.email;
    this.user.password = this.loginForm.value.confirmedPassword;
    console.log(this.loginForm.value);
    this.userSevice.saveUser(this.user).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs');
  }

}
```

and here's the code for the sign-in.page.html

```
<img src="../../assets/logo_main.png" alt="">
<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" >
    <ion-item lines="full">
      <ion-label position="floating">Login</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"  formControlName="login"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item lines="full">
      <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"  formControlName="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item lines="full">
      <ion-label position="floating">Mot de passe</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password"  formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item lines="full">
      <ion-label position="floating">Confirmation du mot de passe</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password"  formControlName="confirmedPassword"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>   
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button type="submit" color="danger" expand="block" (click)="saveUser()" >Créer un compte</ion-button>       
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

I don't understand why it does't work, i do the same for angular and it's working fine ..

Thanks.

Milton

Comment: can you specify what happens? does your console log show undefined inside saveUser or?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko the console log  of my form show this output :

{login: "", email: "", password: "", confirmedPassword: ""} 

And my method show this error message :

ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'login' of undefined
    at SignInComponent.saveUser (sign-in.component.ts:34)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your case, you declare user as a type but it remains 'undefined' as it never gets instantiated with any value. Hence you are receiving the type error.

So inside ngOnInit you should initialize the user with the initial value:

```
this.user = {
      login: null,
      email: null,
      password: null
}
```

or better assign value as an object instead of per property:

```
this.user = {
      login: this.loginForm.value.login,
      email: this.loginForm.value.email,
      password: this.loginForm.value.confirmedPassword
    }
```

The form should work as seen in this stackblitz example I created based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-q62gpm

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, so the problem was that i didn't initialize my user  ? I don't fully understand why this has an effect on the console.log value of the form value

Thanks again !